# Icon usage in HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have started learning html and php. I know very little coding of it. I am confused for using png icons in my action buttons. I have currently text button with css. I want use png icons instead that text buttons. I have used it like below

```html
<td>
   <a href="edit_quotes.php?quotes_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
   <a href="edit_quotes.php?quotes_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">Activate</a>
   <a href="?quotes_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this quotes?');">Delete</a>
</td>
```

Now I want use png icons there instead of text. What should I do for it ?
I have icons located in directory called icons.

Sorry for my little knowledge.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add icon as image in your code, check below snippet

```html
<td><a href="edit_quotes.php?quotes_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary" title="Edit"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff.png&text=E" alt="Edit"/></a>
<a href="edit_quotes.php?quotes_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-primary" title="Activate"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff.png&text=A" alt="Activate"/></a>
<a href="?quotes_id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this quotes?');" title="Delete"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff.png&text=D" alt="Delete"/></a></td>
```

Comment: How can I use from icons directory ?

Comment: You can simple put `image tag` instead of `text`. 
`<img src="your image path" alt="" />`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of your web folder, where **icons** directory is in your web folder.

If you have **icon** directory in your root folder and php file is also in root then you can simply use below syntax :

`<img src="icon/image_name.jpg" alt="" />`

Or you can use complete path for **icon** folder relative to your website url as shown below :

`<img src="http://localhost:8080/websitename/icon/image_name.jpg" alt="" />`